# Why doesn't my OpenFileDialog work?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am trying to save and open a file which consists of a list of objects. My problem right now is that when I open the file I saved nothing happens. The program is supposed to use a dragTo event. When I use that event the object that is dragged gets saved in the list "ojl"
Here is my methods for Save and open.

```
    DragTo dragto1 = new DragTo();
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    BinaryFormatter form = new BinaryFormatter();

 public void Save()  // Method to save list of objects (Save)
    {
        saveDialog.Filter = "dat files (*.dat)|*.dat|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream outStr = new FileStream(saveDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);  //Create new FileStream
            form.Serialize(outStr, dragto1.Ojl);
            outStr.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Open()  // Method for open saved list of objects (Load/Open)
    {
        openDialog.Filter = "dat files (*.dat)|*.dat|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream inStr = new FileStream(openDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open);  //Create new FileStream
            dragto1.Ojl = (List<DrawnObject>)form.Deserialize(inStr);
            inStr.Close();
        }
```

and the list is in another class (DragTo)

```
    private List<DrawnObject> ojl = new List<DrawnObject>();
    public List<DrawnObject> Ojl
    {
        get { return ojl; }
        set { ojl = value; }
    }
```

I also refresh the controller which the objects are inside of. but the list hasn't got the new values in it from the open method. Does the format of the file have anything to do with it (.dat)?

Comment: try changing your `saveDialog.Filter` to something like this 
`savefile.Filter = "Tdat files (*.dat)|*.dat|All files (*.*)|*.*|"` also what is the name of the `saveDialog.FileName`? can you assign one a constant value to test with for example `avefile.FileName = "SaveDialog_TestFile.txt";

Comment: Does the `openFileDialog` display on the screen? If so, it works. Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Its opening and no exceptions.

Comment: `DragTo dragto` are you setting properties to allow dropping / dragging to ? for example `this.AllowDrop = true;` you need to setup Events as well if you have not done so.. [MSDN Drag and Drop Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx)

Comment: allowdrop are true and the events are fixed aswell.

Comment: can you check in your `Bin` Directory and see where the file is being saved to.. what is the `Initial Dir` setup as in your project if that is set.. check there to make sure the file is located there otherwise can you verify what the file path + file name is of the expected file that's suppose to be saved..?

Comment: can you cange AllowDrop=true to `this.AllowDrop = true`

Comment: Didnt make any change :/

Comment: i save the file as .dat and i save it right on my desktop. the problem comes when i shall open the file because when i select the file on my desktop which i saved and opens it with the method open and then refreshes the controller nothing happens.